Will RVO use an existing vector, what's the right pattern to pass a reusable object
Consider this:
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> f() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2};
    return v;
}

void test() {
    auto v = f();
    v = f();           <---- HERE
}

Will the compiler "reuse" the space assigned to v in the call marked with HERE or create a complete new vector?
Alternatively, consider:
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> f(std::vector<int>&& v = {}) {
    // v might not be empty, so be careful!
    v = {1, 2};
    return v;
}

void test() {
    auto v = f();
    v = f(std::move(v));
}


In that approach, a) I don't like that v might not be empty, so one has to be careful in the function and b) v is initialised with a default with is also not optimal.
What's a good pattern to design f in a way that it would potentially get a reusable vector?

The standard way to pass an inout object is to pass it by non-const reference.

Avoid non-const references, pass by pointer. Many style guides suggest it for a very compelling reason: You can tell at the call site (because you see &v) that the function accepts a modifiable handle. A reference means both modifying and non-modifying use cases look the same at the call site, making it harder to reason about the code locally.

This and this might be relevant.

It depends. In your first example, as long as "f" can be inlined, than changes are high that the vector will be reused. If it isn't (like in a debug-build, or if f is a large function), then most likely, no, the vector won't be reused.
I'm not sure how standardized this is, but at least on Windows, the calling-convention for returning a value that is non-pod is, that a reference is passed in the first call-register (RCX), and inside the function the returned value is constructed. This cannot account for reusing an existing value.
In your second example, I don't see your concern about "v" not being empty. So? You move the vector inside the function, meaning you fully expect all values of the calling vector to be taken over. So if the vector has values, then they are gone eigther way. Maybe your actual use-case has a problem with this, but cannot tell, unless you show us the actual case.
Though the second case is also a bit clunky. Moving into the function just to assign and return is a bit weird. If you really need to reuse the vector, I think you just stick to the oldschool way:
void f(std::vector<int>& out)
{
    out = { 1, 2 };
}

This guarantees reuse, and communicates effectively that in your code, you do not want to create or return a vector, but write to a pre-allocated vector object.

It feels you fully ignore what (N)RVO did. It is not some kind of potentially optimizations, it is a language guarantee. The basic idea is to create a new object in the time it is first used in the place of the calling stack frame and not the frame of the called function. Or is it my misinterpretation? (N)RVO has nothing todo with inlining of code at all.

@Klaus RVO in my understanding only applies to the value of a temporary inside the function. You will not get a copy when local "v" is returned. However, you might get a move-assignment when that return-value is then assigned to a pre-existing external variable. The former case will mean no copy at all, since RVO constructs it inside the newly created variable directly. The latter case would require a function to know if it's returned to a new value or an existing one, which it generally cannot.

Agree, it is about reuse in the callers stack... totally different thing. Sorry!
